# Back fill data in table using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ID  Date        NAME    START_TIME              END_TIME            
1   2/15/2017   A       2/15/20173:40:39 PM     2/15/2017 3:41:17 PM
2   2/15/2017   B       2/15/20173:40:39 PM     2/15/2017 3:41:17 PM
3   2/15/2017   C       2/15/20173:40:39 PM     2/15/2017 3:41:17 PM
```

I am facing a problem where I have to back fill my database with these 3 statements From Jan 2016 to Today.
One solution I can try is I can write java code which just loop on and create a new date and new entry for the table and then i can insert using generated query.

But is there any way I can do this using oracle.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: One row per day for each of A, B and C? With what start and end times?

Comment: @jarlh i m using oracle.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes one row per day for A,B and C with start time and end time should be same date, and time  doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

This is a commonly used way to generate dates given a start and an end date, which you can simply join to the list of your names to get what you need:

```
insert into yourTable ( ...)      
with names as (
    select 'A' as name from dual union all
    select 'B' as name from dual union all
    select 'C' as name from dual 
),
dates as (
          select date' 2017-01-01' + level -1 as yourDate
          from dual
          connect by date' 2016-01-01' + level -1 <= date '2017-02-20'
         )
select rownum, name, yourDate
from names
       cross join dates
```

This has to be slightly edited to better suit the number and types of your columns. A small example of how it works:

```
with names as (
    select 'A' as name from dual union all
    select 'B' as name from dual union all
    select 'C' as name from dual 
),
dates as (
            select date' 2017-02-18' + level -1 as yourDate,
            level as lev
            from dual
            connect by date' 2017-02-18' + level -1 <= date '2017-02-20')
select rownum, name, yourDate, lev
from names
       cross join dates
```

gives:

```
    ROWNUM N YOURDATE         LEV
---------- - --------- ----------
         1 A 18-FEB-17          1
         2 B 18-FEB-17          1
         3 C 18-FEB-17          1
         4 A 19-FEB-17          2
         5 B 19-FEB-17          2
         6 C 19-FEB-17          2
         7 A 20-FEB-17          3
         8 B 20-FEB-17          3
         9 C 20-FEB-17          3
```

Answer (score 0):

As a basic concept, something like this would do it... You would need to either adapt for the A, B and C, or repeat for each.

```
with Numbers (NN) as
(
select 1 as NN
from dual
union all
select NN+1
from Numbers
where NN <2000
)
insert into MyTable (ID, Date, Name, StartTime, EndTime)
select NN + 3,  -- If repeating, replace the 3 with the max(id) after each run
       'A', 
       to_date('20170215','YYYYMMDD') - NN, 
       to_date('20170215 154039','YYYYMMDD HH24MISS') - NN,
       to_date('20170215 154117','YYYYMMDD HH24MISS') - NN
from NN
where NN <= 365
```

Comment: Its throwing exception PLS-00182: Identifier cannot be an empty string